# Запустить программу если она закрыта

Tags: delphi

Как постоянно проверять запущена ли другая программа, если нет то запустить ее. Второе приложение иногда вылетает.

Обе программы мои, одна на делфи, вторая на c# - постоянно вылетает ошибка, нужно запускать его. Обе приложения оконные.

Слышал про WinExec, а как сделать чтобы постоянно проверять запущена ли она?

Comment: Самое простое - проверять есть ли окно с нужным именем (программы). Более хитрый вариант - через мьютекс (создавать его программой, и проверять). Более костыльный - писать таймстэмпы в лог, и проверять, если лог замер, значит прога убилась/повисла.

Comment: Если оба приложения ваши, почему бы не сделать перехват исключений в них? Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: я дак за мьютекс, не будет зависимости от класса окна и его названия.

Comment: Kromster дельно написал. И костыльный вариант с проверкой времени изменения log файла иногда самый лучший (позволяет отследить зависание программы).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, повесил на таймер:

```
procedure TFMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
Wnd : THandle;
begin
  Wnd := FindWindow(nil, PChar('app1'));
  if WND > 0 then
  BEGIN
    Memo1.Lines.Add('good')
  END
  else
  BEGIN
    Memo1.Lines.Add('bad');
    WinExec('app1.exe', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  END;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверить запуск можно по наличию хэндла окна FindWindow
`Wnd := FindWindow(PChar('TApplication'), PChar(Application.Title));`

`WND > 0`-  окно найдено.

Если окно найдено, то программа запущена

`Wnd : THandle`

Comment: а как сделать постоянную проверку?

Comment: @Barlukov, по таймеру или в цикле.

Comment: дабы не запутать спрашивающего, в данном виде вызов функции возвращает дескриптор своего окна.